# Define Multi-Rate Network Model state space and transition rates between the states

Tags: markov-process, continuous-time

Assume there's a network with audio and video call classes. Audio call requires 1 channel (b1) and video call classes requires different channels based on the video call type (V_low=2(b2), V_med=3(b3), V_high=4(b4)). Cell size is 5 (C), Voice call arrival rate is 20 calls per hour and video call arrival rate is 0.4 call per hour (both are arriving according to a Poisson process). Audio call duration is exponentially distributed with average 6 minutes and video call duration is 10 minutes. 40% of video calls require high resolution medium and 40% require medium resolution medium and 20% requires low resolution medium. How do I define the state space and the transition rates using continuous-time Markov chain?

I used to define the state space as below.
S = {(0,2), (1,3), (2,4)...(n,m)} where b1.n+(b2+b3+b4)m <= C Am I doing this correct or do I need to create feasible values from all the classes (E.g.: S = {(0,2,0,0), (1,2,0,0)...} )?

Thank you